# my WCF Service running in VS2012 : Cannot obtain Metadata from localhost

Tags: .net, wcf, visual-studio-2012, metadata, config

I know this error has been posted a lot here and I've read countless posts trying to find an answer and I'm still stuck after several hours of work.  Yesterday morning, my service worked perfectly, but by the end of the day it started to display this error.  I did not change my app.config, but was making code changes.  I'm assuming that something in my code changes must have broken things but I cannot figure out what.  I've looked through my event logs but there is nothing there referencing my service.

Although I don't believe there is anything wrong with my config, this is its contents:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="ElectronicContactServiceLibrary.ElectronicContactService">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="ElectronicContactServiceLibrary.IElectronicContactService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8733/Design_Time_Addresses/ElectronicContactServiceLibrary/ElectronicContactService/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, 
      set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True" httpsGetEnabled="True"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, 
      set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment 
      to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

What steps can I take to figure out the issue?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that I added an enum value with an incorrect decoration as I forgot to populate the Value:

```
<DataContract>
Public Enum Status
    <EnumMember(Value:="")>
    NoValue = 0
```